# StackOverflow Exception CSVHelper Writer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, csvhelper

I am getting a stackoverflow exception when writing a new csv file using csvhelper. Exception is raised on the line:

```
csv.WriteRecords(listToSave)
```

Originally thought it was down to using generic `List` but have also tried with a concrete list and can replicate it with any sized list and any type of list.
All lists are created using Entity Framework `.ToList()` have also tried `AsEnumerable()` etc...

Not sure if I'm missing something blindingly obvious?

Any help to resolve, much appreciated.

```
public string SaveTemporaryCsvToFileSystem<T>(IEnumerable<T> listToSave, string fileName)
{
    //Store in folder
    string folder = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Content\\EmailOutput\\Temporary Files\\";
    string filePath = fileName + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Year + ".CSV";

    if(!Directory.Exists(folder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
    }

    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(folder + filePath))
    {
        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
        csv.WriteRecords(listToSave);
    }

    var zippedFile = ZipSecurely(folder + filePath);
    DeleteUnsecureFile(folder + filePath);

    return zippedFile;
}
```

Comment: Is the `T` type an Entity Framework proxied type? If so then (just a hunch) perhaps CsvWriter tries to serialize a collection property (e.g. "Children"), then when doing so, it serializes each Child which has a corresponding "Parent", it proceeds to serialize the Parent which again has "Children" and then an infinite loop occurs.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this was my original thought too but there are no child entities in the lists that are being passed, so doesn't look like it's that

Comment: I think you'll need to show the definition of the type you're trying to save.

Comment: You will definitely have to show the definition, you don't have a [MCVE] without it.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that the class I wanted to write didn't have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, when the type I was saving had a `Uri` property. It seems, that the structure of the `System.Uri` class causes some recursion.

Does your type have any properties, that are not of basic types?